# How to disable tracked changes warning when saving documents

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, document-management

I use tracked changes when drafting documents and collecting review comments.
The company also has custom meta data field populated by our document management system.
We are using office 365.

A while ago (not sure when or with which software version) Word started to show me a dialogue before each save.

[image: MS Word message prior to saving]

I have to press OK to actually save. The '*Tell Me More*' button leads [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-by-inspecting-documents-presentations-or-workbooks-356b7b5d-77af-44fe-a07f-9aa4d085966f?NS=WINWORD&Version=90&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZWD900&HelpId=wdmain11.chm5190102).

This dialogue is tedious as I save often.
It also breaks the work flow with our DMS which saves the file locally and then updates meta data. This process now gets stuck at the message and I often find myself waiting for the document to open when in fact the message is somewhere under another window waiting for me to OK it.

**How can I disable this message?**

Comment: Doesn't the solution from previous versions work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083220/how-to-disable-the-document-being-saved-contains-tracked-changes-word-dialog-u

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to File > Options > Trust Center and click on "Trust Center Settings...".
2. Navigate to "Privacy Options" and then, under "Document-specific settings", disable the first checkbox.
3. Confirm by clicking OK twice.